# To Do list linked to a file on computer

Tags: windows, productivity

I want to create various todo lists in Windows 10 but linked to a file or folder on my computer.

The todo list name must be the name of the file or folder

I need to be able to reorder (change priority) the list at any time.

Clicking on the link of the link in the fileor folder must open the file or folder. Does such software exist?